# Certificate installation problem

Tags: iphone

I want to download my iPhone application into the device. For that i want to know the process to install the certificate (Provisional Profile). So, please give me the idea about the process for that.  I can not install that certificate into my Apple PC. As a result application gives me the error of the certificate.

Comment: Whats the error? What are the steps you followed?

Comment: The internet if full of descriptions for the solution to nearly every imaginable scenario for failed cert's and iphone programming - let a search engine be your friend (btw, the search in SO works too)

Answer (score 2):

login to  the following link

[apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

Then on the left tab , go to certificates and click the tab How To, there they explain step by step guide to install certificate and provision files.